# jQuery - Check a Input Field for a Word in a String

Tags: jquery

I have users that are putting in links to youtube videos and we want to only enable the button if the string (URL) they enter contains the word, 'youtube'.  Below is the code and I can't get it to work how I need it to.  Thanks...

```
var inputValue = $('#inputLink').val();
```

---

```
$('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

$('#inputLink').keyup(function(){
    if (inputValue.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube") >= 0) {
        $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialize `inputValue` each time:

```
$('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

$('#inputLink').keyup(function(){
    var inputValue = this.value;

    if (inputValue.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube") >= 0) {
        $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BGcDg/

---

**Update:** You could also do this with just one line if you wanted to:

```
var youtubeRegex = /youtube/i;

$('#inputLink').keyup(function(){
    $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", !youtubeRegex.test(this.value));
});
```

This will re-disable the field if the user removes "youtube" after entering it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bdmhQ/

Comment: this did it...thanks for helping point that out to me...I'll check the answer when they let me...weird they don't within a time period...